# if $S(a^n+n)=1+S(n)$ for any sufficiently large $n$ if and only if $a$ is a power of $10$

Tags: decimal-expansion

let $a$ be a positive integer such that
$$S(a^n+n)=1+S(n)$$ for any sufficiently large $n$ if  and only if $a$ is a power of $10$

where $S(n)$ is digit sum of a positive integer $n$

if $a$ is a power of $10$,let $a=10^k$,for large $n$,then $10^{kn}>n$,so  It is clear
$$S(a^n+n)=S(10^{kn}+n)=1+S(n)$$
But for other hand,if $S(a^n+n)=1+S(n)$ I can't prove $a$ is a power of $10$

Comment: Have you tried checking when $n$ is a power of $10$ itself?

Comment: Since $S(k) \equiv k\pmod 9$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$, we have $a^n \equiv 1\pmod 9$ for all sufficiently large $n\in \mathbb N$. This leads to $9\mid a-1$. For now, i don't know how to continue.

Comment: +1 for the comment of John Omielan. If $n=10^k$, then the rhs of the equation is 2, so we get $a^{10^k}+10^k=20\cdots 0$ or $a^{10^k}+10^k=10\cdots 010\cdots 0$ for all $k$.